# create csv download for table results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to create a csv file with a download button for my table results view. I am using Laravel framework and am unsure on how exactly to do this.

My controller to get the data.

```
    public function reportFailedPayments(){
    $startdate = Input::get('startdate');
    $enddate = Input::get('enddate');
    $status = Input::get('status');
    $data = Payment::with('purchase', 'history', 'history.billingInformation', 'purchase.user', 'purchase.productInstance', 'purchase.productInstance.product', 'billingInformation')
            ->where('Status', '=',$status)->whereBetween('Payment_Date', array($startdate, $enddate))->orderBy('Payment_Date','desc')->get();
    return View::make('admin.reports.failedPayments.report', array('payments'=>$data));
}

}
```

And here is my table view. Just needing some advice on how exactly to create the DL for the csv.

```
<table class='list'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Customer Email</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Purchase Date</th>
<th>Initial Payment Date</th>
<th>Last Payment Date</th>
<th>Billing Method</th>
<th>Transaction Code</th>
<th>Transaction Message</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($payments as $p)
   <tr>
   <td>{{ $p->purchase->user->Last_Name.', '.$p->purchase->user->First_Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->purchase->user->Email }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->purchase->productInstance->product->Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->purchase->Purchase_Date  }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->Payment_Date  }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->lastHistory()->Process_Time }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->lastHistory()->billingInformation->Payment_Type == PaymentType::PayPal ?     "PayPal" :
   CreditCardType::ToString($p->lastHistory()->billingInformation->CCType)." Ending In     ".$p->lastHistory()->billingInformation->CCLast4 }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->lastHistory()->Trans_Response_Code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $p->lastHistory()->Trans_Response_Text }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I won't write all the code for you. This just isn't the purpose of StackOverflow...
However I hope I can point you in the right direction with this answer.
Your problem can be split in two tasks. One being generating the CSV file and then serve the download.

### Generating the CSV file

You'll find a lot of code snippets on the internet. Here's one I found and modified a bit

```
$csvData = $yourCollection->toArray();
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'csv_'); // create a temporary file in the system's default tmp directory
$file = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach($csvData as $row){
    fputcsv($file, $row, ';'); // 3rd parameter is optional (default: ',')
}
fclose($file);
```

Now we have a csv file in our temp folder, ready to be downloaded. Laravel gives you a very way to download files.

### Serving the file for download

In your controller action:

```
$response = Response::download($filename);
unlink($filename); // lets not forget to delete the file or they will pile up in your temp folder
return $response;
```

Maybe you also need to send some additional headers (e.g. for specifying a filename that the user sees) but I'll leave that up to you.

And here are some references to the functions used in the code:

- [Laravel Response::download](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses)
- [PHP fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)
- [PHP tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Comment: This helps a lot, I was trying to find a way to do it utilizing laravel a little more. Right now I am just using a jquery function that retuns the csv data for the table. This was just more for seeing how people who are more familiar with Laravel would approach.